# jQuery.each() counts removed element in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make order details and I have this figure(see photo): So the **parent container** of these items is `.co-items-body-inner` which is **totally removed** in the DOM (when I **clicked each** `.btn-cancel-order`).

```
<div class="co-items-body">
        <div class="co-items-body-inner">
            <div class="co-item-body-left">
                <img src="assets/images/checkout-item.png" alt="Item1"/>
            </div>
            <div class="co-item-body-right">
                <div class="cibr-title">
                    <h1>Parrot Clasp [218]</h1>
                    <h2>6mm 9ct YG [218A6]</h2>
                </div><!--end cibr-title-->
                <div class="cibr-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="btn-minus">-</li>
                        <li><input type="text" name="itemcount1" id="itemcount1" class="itemcount" value="2" readonly/></li>
                        <li class="btn-plus">+</li>
                        <li class="amt-per-piece">$7.80</li>
                        <li><img class="btn-cancel-order" src="assets/images/checkout-btn-close.png" alt="Close"/></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--end cibr-body-->
            </div><!--end co-item-body-right-->
        </div><!--end co-items-body-inner-->
        <div class="co-items-body-inner">
            <div class="co-item-body-left">
                <img src="assets/images/checkout-item.png" alt="Item1"/>
            </div>
            <div class="co-item-body-right">
                <div class="cibr-title">
                    <h1>Parrot Clasp [218]</h1>
                    <h2>6mm 9ct YG [218A6]</h2>
                </div><!--end cibr-title-->
                <div class="cibr-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="btn-minus">-</li>
                        <li><input type="text" name="itemcount2" id="itemcount2" class="itemcount" value="2" readonly/></li>
                        <li class="btn-plus">+</li>
                        <li class="amt-per-piece">$7.80</li>
                        <li><img class="btn-cancel-order" src="assets/images/checkout-btn-close.png" alt="Close"/></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--end cibr-body-->
            </div><!--end co-item-body-right-->
        </div><!--end co-items-body-inner-->
        <div class="total-amount-container">
            <ul>
                <li><p>Sub-Total: <span class="sub-total">$15.60</span></p></li>
                <li><p>Shipping: <span class="shipping-amt">$15.00</span></p></li>
                <li><p>Grand Total: <span class="grandtotal">$30.60</span></p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="co-items-links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shipping Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Returns and Corrections</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--END co-items-body-->
```

[image]

So I put this code in my `close button(X)` like so:

```
  $(document).on('click','.btn-cancel-order',function(){
    $(this).closest('div').parent().fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(this).closest('div').parent().remove();
    });

    $('.itemcount').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
 });
```

The `.itemcount` class here is the selector of my `input field`, so my question is: Why is that when `.btn-cancel-order` is being triggered it gives me two logs which is 2?

**Supposedly it will give me 1 log in my console** what I'm missing here? Do I need to reset my `$.each() function` if that is the case how? I'm new to this so please bear with me.

Comment: Hey, unrelated but you can chain remove() with your fadeOut, less code, cleaner :)

Comment: So you have code in EACH of `X` button?

Comment: You have two elements iwth .itemcount class and You select both of them here "$('.itemcount')" thats why You get 2 logs. Please provide your html

Comment: Yes I guess? I have  $('.itemcount').each when $(document).ready and this one in clicked event

Comment: Move your Js code in header, not copy same script for every button!

Comment: @Justinas So it counts even if I remove it then $.each again?

Comment: Try moving `$.each` inside of `fadeOut` call back function

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that fadeOut has a delay so you should do your action in fadeOut callback like that:

```
$(document).on('click','.btn-cancel-order',function(){
    $(this).closest('.co-items-body-inner').fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(this).closest('.co-items-body-inner').remove();

        // Your item was removed
        $('.itemcount').each(function(){
            $(this).css('outline', '1px solid red');
        });
    });

    // Your item isn't removed yet
        $('.itemcount').each(function(){
            $(this).css('outline', '1px solid red');
        });
 });
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be removing $(this).closest('.co-items-body-inner') ?

Comment: It goes the same way tho.

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza: Try the answer in this post, `this` in the animation callback refers to the element being animated and I think that is the element you want to remove.

Comment: @LoyaltyTechnology do you have teamviewer or something we can connect remotely?